# Is there an api to programmatically invoke snap layout?

Tags: winapi

I wrote some logic to snap my window to left/right half or 1/4 of the screen. And I still want to utilize the `explorer`'s built-in snap layout feature (that thing when you drag a window to the border of the monitor, it shows suggestions to how to split the rest of your screen space). How to achieve that?

Comment: It's unclear what code you wrote or what behavior you are after. Opting in to snap layout is a bit indirect (by handling the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message). You don't get to decide the portion your window will occupy, but you can get the default UI to show up (see [Support snap layouts for desktop apps on Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu)).

Comment: @IInspectable I am mimicking the windows 11 Snap layout feature in windows 10(by first snapping my windows, then call the explorer's feature, as the question asking)

Comment: No, Microsoft have never released an API for "snap" functionality. There's no way to restore a window as snapped, even if that's what the user wants.

Comment: Check [Launching the Snipping Tool or Snip & Sketch App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-screen-snipping#launching-the-snipping-tool-or-snip--sketch-app). *The **ms-screensketch**: URI allows you to programatically launch the Snipping Tool app (on Windows 11) or Snip & Sketch app (on Windows 10), and open a specific image in that app for annotation*.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Not "snip". It's "snap", the thing that `explorer.exe` shows to layout windows.

Comment: According to [Support snap layouts for desktop apps on Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu), *Snap layouts are a new Windows 11 feature to help introduce users to the power of window snapping. Snap layouts are easily accessible by hovering the mouse over a window's maximize button or pressing Win + Z.* You may [Synthesize the keystrokes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) but there is not a direct API.